# MVC 3 Route Constraints that check the POST

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have a method that accepts some JSON data and binds the data to some variables. The route only has the method name in it, nothing else.

Is it possible to have a route constraint that looks at the POST data and checks some variables to determine whether it is the correct route?

The methods:

```
public ActionResult GetDataV1(string userId)
{
    // Do stuff one way
}

public ActionResult GetDataV2(string userId)
{
    // Do stuff another way
}
```

The routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "API GetData V1",
    "GetData",
    new { controller = "API", action = "GetDataV1" },
    new { version = new APIVersionRoutingConstraint("1") }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "API GetData V2",
    "GetData",
    new { controller = "API", action = "GetDataV2" },
    new { version = new APIVersionRoutingConstraint("2") }
);
```

The client would post `{ "version":"1", "userId":"mrjohn" }` to `/GetData` and would get response from `GetDataV1`. The `APIVersionRoutingConstraint` would make sure the right method is called depending on the `version` variable.

Would it be good practice to try to deserialise the request stream inside the constraint?  Maybe it would be better to put the version in the URL like `/GetData/1` and the other variables in the JSON body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the `APIVersionRoutingConstraint` like this:

```
public class APIVersionRoutingConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private string _versionNumber;

    public APIVersionRoutingConstraint(string versionNumber)
    {
        _versionNumber = versionNumber;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string version = null;

        if (httpContext.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
        {
            string body = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            httpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            var vals = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(body) as Dictionary<string, object>;
            if (vals.ContainsKey("version"))
                version = vals["version"].ToString();
        }

        // Must have version to pass constraint
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(version) && version == _versionNumber;
    }
}
```

It's not super-efficient I guess, but it gets the job done. Only the route that matches the version in the POST body gets used.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to check the version as a route constraint, why not go to one Action that then checks the version to execute the appropriate work?

I haven't tested this, but the idea is:

```
public ActionResult GetData(string userId, int version)
{
    switch(version)
    {
        case 1:
            return GetDataV1(userId);
        case 2:
            return GetDataV2(userId);
        // You could always add more cases here as you get more versions, 
        // and still only have the one route
        default:
            // Probably more appropriate to return a result that contains error info,
            // but you get the idea
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("version");
    }
}

// Made these private since they are called from the public action
private ActionResult GetDataV1(string userId)
{
    // Do stuff one way
}

private ActionResult GetDataV2(string userId)
{
    // Do stuff another way
}
```

And then you only need the one route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "GetData",
    "GetData",
    new { controller = "API", action = "GetData" },
    new { version = "\d+" } // Require a numeric version
);
```

Comment: Yup, that would probably work. But what if the methods have different signatures? And I don't like the switch, wanted that done by the route constraints.

Comment: And where does the route in your example get the version value? Is it coming from the query string or the body?

Comment: The model binder should pick it up from the query string or the form, wherever it is; I'm testing this now. If you want your constraint to handle it, it would need to read the httpContext.Request.InputStream

Comment: BTW, your idea to put the version in the URL is a very valid alternative, especially in the case where you'll have different signatures. This answer was to handle the presented case where there was clear commonality.

Comment: @Ed Despite the upvotes this answer has gotten, I'm afraid it actually does not work as I expected. I won't have time to correct it right now, maybe later, but I hope it sparks some ideas. Again, putting the version in the URL is a very valid (and perhaps even simpler) alternative. Good luck.